# Magnolia not flowering well

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, tree-care

My Magnolia ‘Vulcan’ flowers are not looking right. Attached photos are all new growth (in Australia, just entering Spring). Any thoughts as to the issue?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Dry spring?  Cold Spring? tell us what the weather has been

Comment: Spring has only just started. And there has been a decent amount of rain so far.